# What is the maximum amount of carbon atoms that can comprise a fullerene?

Tags: synthesis, theoretical-chemistry, materials, carbon-allotropes

As the fullerene sum formula can be defined as $\ce{C_n}$ with $n$ being any even integer number, is there any fundamental theoretical limit as to how big $n$ can get?

If there is no limit to the chemistry, but there are difficulties in synthesizing large fullerenes, what has been the largest fullerene ever made? Would there be any differences in behaviour?

Comment: $n$ is not just any integer. It can't be odd, to begin with. Now to the point: just as you expected, there is no fundamental upper bound.

Comment: At some point, the molecule would be so big that it cannot exist at a given temperature, because it is also stiff (has a 1D long range order). I will then just snap in two with a certain half-life time. I don't think a controlled synthesis can ever get *close* to that value.

Comment: Btw.: it is extremely hard to produce macroscopic amounts of very large molecules (a *substance*) with a defined, uniform molecular weight, i.e. number of carbon atoms in this case. For polyethylene, the record is afaik $\ce{C390H782}$, far, far below the average size of a UHMWPE molecule (easily a million carbon atoms).

Comment: One can consider a capped nanotube a fullerene.

Comment: $\ce{C3996}$. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene

Comment: Multiple questions here - you might be more likely to get answers if you split it into (at least) two questions. Anyway to address the part which people haven't discussed so far in principle if you are considering a single molecule you will always get discrete energy levels. Bands are a result of the translational symmetry of a perfectly periodic system such as a crystal. No periodicity, no bands, and a single molecule won't ever display perfect periodicity. That's not to say the energy levels won't get very, very close and look similar to bands. But bands they won't be.

Comment: @IanBush the OP recently expanded the question and added the explanation "Added feedback from the answers and questions, which expands the scope of interests that might help narrow down an answer." I agree it may make this harder to answer and this was not the question to which I added the bounty.

Comment: Will rollback the answer as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the rollback! I think you wrote a near-perfect question in the beginning, and that the reason there hasn't been an actual answer posted (despite the helpful comments) is that it turns out to be an interesting and not-so-easy question to answer; the best kind in my opinion :-)

Comment: I'll give this a day or so, then add another bounty. We'll get this answered!

Comment: To be honest I don't think you will get an answer to the first question 'is there any fundamental theoretical limit as to how big "n" can get?' as I suspect large fullerenes will be thermodynamically unstable WRT decomposition to both smaller fullerenes and graphite, and so the question becomes why is this kinetically infeasible, which is very hard. So you are left with a literature search for the biggest fullerene synthesised or detected.

Answer (score 5):

Not a full answer, but possibly the start of one. I came across a [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01416354/document)[1] discussing some mathematical properties of fullerene graphs. In section 4.2, they give a formula for a lower bound on the diameter based on the number of vertices $n$, assuming there are only pentagonal and hexagonal face.
$$\text{diam}(F)\ge\frac{\sqrt{24n-15}}{6}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Given a lower bound on the diameter, it may be possible to prove that a ball of a certain size would be mechanically unstable. I suspect this would give a fairly high upper bound on the size and it wouldn't account for the wide [variety of shapes](https://wires.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1002/wcms.1207) that are possible for fullerenes[2], but this would at least be a starting point.

This could hopefully be refined somewhat by using the largest synthesized/reported fullerene size as a lower bound. Thus far $\ce{C_{500}}$ is the largest fullerene I can find experimental evidence for [3,4]. I suspect this is still pretty far from the largest possible fullerene, even considering just spherical/icosahedral structures.

Based on [2], you will need to look for some kind of mechanical/kinetic stability limit for the upper bound, as the paper suggests that fullerenes should increase in thermodynamic stability as $n$ increases, approaching the structure of graphene or a infinite nanotube.

1. Vesna Andova, František Kardoš, Riste Škrekovski. Mathematical aspects of fullerenes. Ars Mathematica Contemporanea, DMFA Slovenije, 2016, 11, pp.353 - 379. ffhal-01416354f
2. WIREs Comput Mol Sci 2015, 5:96–145. doi: 10.1002/wcms.1207
3. Shinohara, H., Sato, H., Saito, Y., Izuoka, A., Sugawara, T., Ito, H., Sakurai, T. and Matsuo, T. (1992), Extraction and mass spectroscopic characterization of giant fullerences up to C500. Rapid Commun. Mass Spectrom., 6: 413-416. https://doi.org/10.1002/rcm.1290060702
4. Front. Chem., 03 December 2020 | https://doi.org/10.3389/fchem.2020.607712

Comment: *really cool paper!* I've just asked [What does 3-regularity mean in the context of this diagram of a fullerene?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4287792/284619) in Math SE.

Comment: While this is only a start, I found the paper really interesting and salient, and it has got me thinking, and I'm loath to waste a good bounty. `+200` :-)

Comment: @uhoh Thank you! I'll try to keep expanding the answer as I run into anything that might fit. I can at least now give a (probably very loose) lower bound with experimental evidence of at least $\ce{C_{500}}$.